# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Entry' and 'Entry'

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey Guys I have an Error in Python Tkinter.

I wanted to make an simple Calculator:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

intery=ttk.Entry(root, width=8)
intery.pack()
intery2=ttk.Entry(root, width=8)
intery2.pack()

def su():
    intery.config(intery + intery2)
    print(su)

btn=ttk.Button(root, text="+", command=su)
btn.pack()
```

But I encounter an Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Entry' and 'Entry'
```

Comment: what do you expect su() to do?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried researching what "unsupported operand" means?

Answer (score 1):

to get the text value of an `tk.Entry` use `entry.get()`

however `"5" + "6"` is equal to `"56"`

so you probably need

```
int(entry.get())
```

or

```
float(entry.get())
```

Im not sure if this answers your question or not ... since your question is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks Joran. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
intery.config(int(intery) + int(intery2))
```

Comment: Try expanding your answer to explain why your proposed solution would work and what was wrong with the orginal. Just posting a 1 liner without explanation is considered bad form.